# How do you automatically go to a folder whenever you use vagrant with "vagrant ssh" with Laravel Homestead?

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I'm asking so I don't have to "cd" everytime I use Vagrant. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `cd dir-name` to your .bashrc file inside your vm. So once you ssh into your vagrant machine it'll automatically run and change the directory.

On ubuntu .bashrc file is located in home (/home/vagrant) directory.

Alternatively you can connect to your vagrant box through starndard ssh command. This will allow you to specify the directory name at the connect time and have more freedom.

For example
`ssh -p 2222 vagrant@localhost -t "cd dir-name ; /bin/bash"`

You can see vagrant ssh config using below command. So you can check your port, user.. etc.
`vagrant ssh-config`